# Dolphin uses ftp not sftp when adding network folder

Tags: ftp, sftp, vsftpd, dolphin

I'm trying to connect to my server with sftp. The server is working just fine. I connected to it from FileZilla. Then I was able to connect to it using Dolphin by just typing in the address: `sftp://username:password@domain/`. This worked and I was even able to transfer files.

However, I would like to create a directory to save this for future use, so that I don't have to type that in every time. It seems that "Add Network Directory" uses ftp instead of sftp, making it so that I cannot connect to the server. I can find no way to make it use sftp, is there a way to do this?

Every time that I try to connect, it asks for the password, I enter it, and then I get this error:

```
  Server replied:
  530 Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption.
  Do you want to retry?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's your server and you have SSH access, than maybe setup a SSH connection instead and use `fish://username@remotehost` as the URI in dolphin.

There is a big difference between `SFTP` (FTP over SSH) vs `FTPS` which is FTP over TLS. It gets more complicated because FTPS has an implicit and explicit mode, implicit uses a dedicate port and connects using TLS, while the explicit mode uses the normal ftp port and switches to TLS with startTLS command.

Looking at the source:
https://github.com/KDE/dolphin/blob/c836cf010c12858a7f3a4943c06f9de2b9f31a14/doc/index.docbook#L609

The docs imply the dolphin supports SFTP and FISH, both of which use SSH. I can find no mention of FTPS, so perhaps it doesn't support that?

Comment: I made a typo, I used sftp to connect successfully. But in the `Add Network Folder -> FTP` there is not option for sftp, so it just kept refusing my connection. I assume there must be a way to use sftp for that.  However, I used ssh instead and it worked, so thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably did something wrong. I've successfully created SFTP folder to my server by these steps

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

By the way, you probably shouldn't use `fish://` protocol, it is fallback protocol for ssh servers which don't support sftp and it's not fast. Default sshd servers confugured with sftp enabled by default.

Comment: Yep, the answer above gave me the way to do that. I was using FTP in the first step.